# asp.net not reading latest and all emails

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

I was trying to read gmail using ASP.NET. I'm not getting latest emails as well as I'm getting only few mails. Using Java, I was able to read all mails successfully but with ASP.NET, I'm having problems. I have gone through lot of examples on the net but none of them are working for me (strange). The code take ages to read emails. I tried to read only 20 emails and it was waiting for more than 2 minutes.

I'm using OpenPop library

Here is my code:

```
        Pop3Client pop3Client = new Pop3Client();
        pop3Client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
        pop3Client.Authenticate("##email##", "##password##");

        int count = pop3Client.GetMessageCount();
        DataTable dtMessages = new DataTable();
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("MessageNumber");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("From");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("Subject");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("DateSent");
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = count; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            Message message = pop3Client.GetMessage(i);
            dtMessages.Rows.Add();
            dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["MessageNumber"] = i;
            dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["From"] = message.Headers.From.Address;
            dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["Subject"] = message.Headers.Subject;
            dtMessages.Rows[dtMessages.Rows.Count - 1]["DateSent"] = message.Headers.DateSent.ToLocalTime();
            counter++;
            if (counter > 20)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        gvEmails.DataSource = dtMessages;
        gvEmails.DataBind();
```

Are there changes I can make to this code to get it to work, so that it reads emails from Gmail with latest first?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using the MailSystem.NET api. Here is my code:

```
    public void ReadEmails()
    {
        MailRepository rep = new MailRepository("imap.gmail.com", 993, true, @"email@gmail.com", "password");

        DataTable dtMessages = new DataTable();
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("MessageNumber");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("From");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("Subject");
        dtMessages.Columns.Add("DateSent");

        int x = 0;
        //foreach (Message email in rep.GetUnreadMails("Inbox"))
        foreach (Message email in rep.GetAllMails("Inbox"))
        {
            dtMessages.Rows.Add();

            dtMessages.Rows[x]["MessageNumber"] = x;
            dtMessages.Rows[x]["From"] = email.From;
            dtMessages.Rows[x]["Subject"] = email.Subject;
            dtMessages.Rows[x]["DateSent"] = email.Date.ToShortDateString();

            ++x;

            if (x >= 20) break;
        }

        gvEmails.DataSource = dtMessages;
        gvEmails.DataBind();
    }
```